# Using Multiprocessing With SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a task which reads data from two tables (let's call these *source_table_1* and *source_table_2*) in a local postgres database, does some processing (we'll call this *do_something*), and then saves the output to another table (let's call this *target_table*) in the same postgres database.  There is a *pairs* table which lets *do_something* know which indices from both tables to query in order to do the processing.  *pairs* looks like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
| source_table_1_ind  |source_table_2_ind|
|---------------------|------------------|
|             1       |        51        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|             1       |        106       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           ...       |         ...      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I am trying to utilize multiprocessing to have my machine work in parallel on batches created from the *pairs* table.

So far what I have is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# filepath of text file which contains sql credentials
sql_config_file = "D:/..."

# get total size of pairs table
pairs_size = engine.execute('select count(*) from pairs;').scalar()

# divide into chunks of 150K
chunk_no = math.ceil(pairs_size/150000)
chunks = np.array(split(range(pairs_size),chunk_no)

# create a tuple called arg_list which we can feed into the function we wish to work in parallel
arg_list = []
for i in chunks:
  arg_list.append([sql_config_file, np.min(i), np.max(i)])

# convert to tuple
arg_list = tuple(arg_list)

# set number of cpus
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
# where the magic should happen
# first work on the first chunk so that the table is created in the schema
do_something(arg_list[0])
# now work on rest of chunks so their results can be appended to table made in above line
pool.imap(do_something, arg_list[1:])
pool.close
pool.join
```

*do_something* would look like:

```
def do_something(x):
  sql_config_file = x[0]
  lower = x[1] + 1
  upper = x[2] + 1
  
  # create sql engine using the text file
  with open(sql_config_file) as config_file:
    conn_config = json.load(config_file)
  engine = create_engine(...)

  # query pairs that are in this particular batch
  query = f"""select source_table_1_ind, source_table_2_ind from (
          select pairs.*, row_number()
          over () as rnum
          from pairs) df
          where df.rnum between {lower} and {upper};"""
  
  # query source_table_1
  source_1_filter = tuple(pairs.source_table_1_ind)
  df1_query = f"""select * from source_table_1 where index in {source_table_1_ind};"
  df1 = pd.read_sql(df1_query, engine)
  
  # query source_table_2
  source_2_filter = tuple(pairs.source_table_2_ind)
  df2_query = f"""select * from source_table_2 where index in {source_table_2_ind};"  
  df2 = pd.read_sql(df2_query, engine)

  # the function, intentionally left blank
  output = sub_function(df1, df2)
  output.to_sql(target_table, engine, schema = "...", if_exists = 'append', index = 
                False, chunksize = 10000)
```

The above code runs with no errors.  The row count of the *target_table* is the same as the row count of *pairs*, which is a good sign.  However, when actually comparing the indices which were processed from *source_table_1* and *source_table_2*, *target_table* consistently has fewer unique indices.  In other words, while the volume of rows outputted is correct, there are duplicate rows being processed and/or output.  It should be noted that when the pool CPUS is set to 1 (meaning no parallel processing is going on), the output is perfect.  It is only when the number of CPUS is greater than 1 that this error occurs.

My guess is that something goes wrong when the different processes try to query the same table, or possibly when writing to the same table, but I am new to multiprocessing so this is nothing more than a hunch.

What can be done to make the code work with the desired output?

Comment: Without an ORDER BY, row_number() is free to assign numbers in whatever order it finds convenient, which may differ between connections.

Comment: That seems to have solved it, thank you!